# Lua - how to use the operator "and" in the table?

Tags: lua

I have a code that works properly. He prints "ok".

```
data = "on482654225954"

  if data:find("on.") then
    start, stop = data:find("on.")
    local a = 0 
    for i=stop,stop+11 do
      if data:sub(stop+a,stop+a):match("[0-9]") then
        t = { [a] = data:sub(stop+a,stop+a) }
        a = a + 1 
        if t[0] == "4" then
          print("ok")
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The code below does not work properly. It does not print "ok".

```
data = "on482654225954"

  if data:find("on.") then
    start, stop = data:find("on.")
    local a = 0 
    for i=stop,stop+11 do
      if data:sub(stop+a,stop+a):match("[0-9]") then
        t = { [a] = data:sub(stop+a,stop+a) }
        a = a + 1 
        if t[0] == "4" and t[5] == "4" and t[11] == "4" then
          print("ok")
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

How do you get the above code to work properly?

**EDIT:**

Program output.

```
Program 'lua.exe' started in 'C:\Users\pic.pic-Komputer\Downloads\ZeroBraneStudio\myprograms' (pid: 2628).
0   4
1   8
2   2
3   6
4   5
5   4
6   2
7   2
8   5
9   9
10  5
11  4
Program completed in 0.06 seconds (pid: 2628).
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `t`? What value does it have?

Comment: Yes. Above I added the program output.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It seems that `data:match("on4....4.....4")` suffices.

Comment: I don't see the output of `t`.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your code can be replaced by this:

```
if data:match("on4....4.....4") then
   print("ok")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

t is a table that never contains more than one element.

```
t = { [a] = data:sub(stop+a,stop+a) }
a = a + 1 
if t[0] == "4" and t[5] == "4" and t[11] == "4" then
   print("ok")
end
```

If you have only 1 element you can never have 3 elements have some value at the same time.